Iterate over divs within an div
how can I iterate through the divs inside one div, and if they all have the same 'display' value('none'), display a message?
I'm just learning and I need to use it one hundred percent
jQuery
<div class="test1">
 <div class="test2" style="display:none">
  
 </div>
 <div class="test2" style="display:none">
  
 </div>
 <div  class="test2" style="display:none">
  
 </div>
 <div  class="test2" style="display:none">
  
 </div>
</div>

I tried it using jQuery.each
  jQuery('.test1 > .test2').each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).css('display') == 'none'){
        jQuery('.test_message').text('nothing');
    }
})


jQuery.each() should work. Please show what you tried so we can help you to debug it

If you support jQuery, you also support regular JS. In regular JS that would be if([...document.querySelectorAll( 'div > div' )].filter(v => v.style.display !== 'none').length === 0) document.querySelector( '.test-message' ).textContent = "Nothing is displayed"; or the like.

Also, if you're starting out, I would suggest you rethink your goal of using 'one hundred percent jQuery'. jQuery was a fantastic library, but there are other libraries and approaches which are more relevant to modern development. Your time would be better spent learning plain JS first, then a framework such as React, Angular etc.

by the way, this is actually the shortest way possible: [...document.querySelectorAll('.test1 > .test2')].every(el => el.style.display === 'none'); to find out if all of those divs met that condition or not (true/false). Since ES6, javascript became something much more powerful than  jquery can offer .. that's why you should leave it behind (and it was almost 10 years ago!)

Your selector jQuery('.test_message') will not find any element, based on the HTML you have shared so far.

The issue with your current logic is that you are testing each .test2 div individually, then outputting the message based on that single element. You instead need to check all the elements first, then output the message if necessary.
To do that you can store a flag to determine the state of the divs, then change that flag if any one of them does not match that state. Here's a working example:


jQuery($ => {
  let allHidden = true;

  $('.test1 > .test2').each(function() {
    if ($(this).css('display') !== 'none') {
      allHidden = false;
      return;
    }
  })

  if (allHidden) {
    $('.test_message').text('nothing');
  }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">
  <div class="test2" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="test2" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="test2" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="test2" style="display: none"></div>
</div>

<div class="test_message"></div>



It would also be possible to do this without an explicit loop by using the :visible selector:


jQuery($ => {
  if (!$('.test1 > .test2:visible').length) {
    $('.test_message').text('nothing');
  }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">
  <div class="test2" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="test2" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="test2" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="test2" style="display: none"></div>
</div>

<div class="test_message"></div>



Finally, note that in the examples above I used a shorthand document.ready handler, which aliases the $ variable. This means you are safe to use the $ prefix instead of the verbose jQuery keyword, without it affecting any other scripts which may also be using $.

Some of the other solutions will fail if the display value is set in external CSS
Instead use checkVisibility
Also note I use the more readable Array.from instead of the [...collection] spread operator to get the array methods available on the collection


const allHidden = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.test1 > .test2'))
  .every(el => !el.checkVisibility());

document.getElementById('testMessage').textContent = allHidden ? 'all child elements are hidden' : 'some child elements are visible';
.text3 { display: none; }
<div class="test1">
  <div class="test2" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="test2" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="test2 text3"></div>
  <div class="test2" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
<span id="testMessage"></span>



If you MUST use jQuery, then try


const $test2Elements = $('.test1 > .test2')
const allHidden = $test2Elements
  .map(function() { return $(this).is(":visible") }) // jQuery map
  .get() // get the array
  .every(e => !e); // look at each and return if true was found or run through all false
  
$("#testMessage").text(allHidden ? 'all child elements are hidden' : 'some child elements are visible');
.text3 { display: none; }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test1">
  <div class="test2" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="test2" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="test2 text3"></div>
  <div class="test2" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
<span id="testMessage"></span>




The easiest way is to change your logic. You can select all elements that have not the style="display:none" attribute and check the length of the Node List with !NodeList.length. If this statement is true, then all elements will have the attribute as nothing is returned:


const visibleChildElements = document.querySelectorAll('.test1 > .test2:not([style*="display:none"])');

if (!visibleChildElements.length) {
  console.log('all child elements are hidden');
} else {
  console.clear();
}
<div class="test1">
  <div class="test2" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="test2" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="test2" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="test2" style="display:none"></div>
</div>



As side-note: As said you should not focus on 100% jQuery in 2024. even Bootstrap-5 got rid of jQuery 2 years ago as it makes no longer sense. It is "outdated" as plain Javascript caught up with the functionality.
If you want to select all child elements in JS you could also use querySelector('element').children

Just to make a note on this, it would only work if you set style="display:none" directly in your HTML. It would be broken if you put the CSS in an external stylesheet, or add any other CSS properties in the HTML, but it certainly is the simplest approach in plain JS.
